# How to install CyanogenMod on an MK808?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing

How does one install CyanogenMod on the MK808 MiniPC? I can't find a good tutorial nor can I get it to work myself.

At this point I'm hoping I didn't brick my device. I attempted to follow a YouTube video where a guy installs some operating system into it. But the guy never said a word, or at least no word that I could understand. You see he was Chinese and the computer he was on was in Chinese.

I could tell that I have the same tool that he does this "RKBatchTool.exe" thing. So I tried to follow it I downloaded the Cyanogenmod 10.1 for RockChip 3066 devices. I also downloaded and installed the RockUSB drivers. I got it to connect, loaded the image into the batch tool thing and told it to upgrade.

I got errors and now I don't know what to do. I Googled around for a good hour or so but I can't find a tutorial or a how to. Not even on the Cyanogen page where they say they have a howto page but that just goes to a 404 error. The device packaging says its an MK808, [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009OX22B4) is the exact device. To add insult to injury, I can find all kinds of videos of people who have it working. Thanks for the any help!

Comment: apparently you missed this part of my comment: "you are going to have to include more details about what you've already done and what the current state of your device is." on SO...

Comment: yea... i just read that part